# Time-Stamping servers API (what signtool uses)

Tags: visual-studio, security, digital-signature, signtool

What is the input that (code signing) time stamping servers expect? And what format is the reply?

I've searched VeriSign's site (and more) but found nothing but directions to use tools like signtool. What I want is the ability to create something like signtool from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To create signtool from scratch, start with the [osslsigncode source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/), as it does roughly the same thing.

For RFC 3161 timestamp servers (supported by signtool), the request and response formats are publicly documented and supported by Openssl.  If you use Wireshark to examine the network packets sent by signtool to the timestamp server you'll find them very similar to the [openssl ts](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ts.html) output.